# How to change Minimum Time and Maximum Time in AngularJS ui.calendar

Tags: angularjs, ui-calendar

I am working on a ui.calendar provided by AngularJS. By default the minimum time is 12 AM and maximum time is 11:30. I have made a bit changes to display time for every 30 mins.

I want to display the minimum time dynamically according to different users. Even if dynamically is not possible, I need to display it from 8AM.

I have tried so many answers on other similar questions but those are not working for me.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: As far as i know angular ui calendar is not that much customisable.